# Using Recursion/Backtracking to create and solve a sudoku puzzle

Tags: c++, recursion, sudoku, backtracking

For my computer class, my teacher wants us to use recursion or backtracking to create and solve an nXn size sudoku puzzle.  The puzzle has to be dynamically allocated and the only rules for the puzzle is that there can be no repetition in any rows or columns.  Diagonals and smaller sub-squares can have repeats.  Here is what I have written so far.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<time.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
using namespace std;


void fill_puzzle(int **array, int size);
void delete_puzzle(int array, int size);
bool check_filled(int **array, int size);

bool check_correct(int **array, int size){
    int temp=0;
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<size; j++){
            for (int k=0;k<size;k++){
                if (array[i][k]==array[i][j])
                    return false;
                else
                    return true;
            }
        }
    }
}           

void fill_puzzle(int **array, int size){
    srand(time(NULL));
    int random_number;
    random_number=(rand()%size);
    while(check_correct(array,size)==false)
        for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
            for (int j=0; j<size; j++){
                array[i][j]=random_number;
                if (check_correct(array, size) ==false)
                    fill_puzzle(array, size);
                else
                    cout << array[i][j];
            }
        }                   
}

void delete_puzzle(int **array, int size){
for (int i=0; i<size; i++){
    delete [] array[i];
}
delete []array;
}

int main(){
int  size=0;
int **array;
cout << "Hello, what size puzzle would you like to create? Please type 1 number. Example: 3 would make a 3x3 sudoku puzzle."<<endl;
cin >> size;
if (size <= 0){
    cout << "The size you have chosen will not work, please choose a number greater than 0." << endl;
    cin >> size;
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++){
    array=new int*[size];
    array[size]=new int [size];

}
}
else {
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++){
    array=new int*[size];
    array[size]=new int [size];
}
fill_puzzle(array,size);
delete_puzzle(array, size);


}
return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile, I get a segmentation error, and using GDB it says that the error occurs in check_correct in the line with if (array[i][k]==array[i][j]). Thanks in advance.

Comment: compiling wouldn't give you a segmentation fault, you are running it.

Comment: yeah that's what i meant

Answer (score 0):

As I can see so far, the code for allocating memory for the 2D array is not correct and the segmentation fault is caused by accessing illegal memory since you didn't allocate properly.

```
for (int i=0; i<size; i++){
    array=new int*[size]; // move it out of loop
    array[size]=new int [size]; //array[size]?!
```

try this:

```
    array = new int*[size];
    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        array[i] = new int[size];
```

There are others problems(`fill_puzzle()` stuck in an infinite recursion, it leads your stack grow bigger and bigger, until you get a segmentation fault) in your sudoku solver, use a debugger to solve it.

Comment: I wanted to avoid using a class in my program just for simplicity sake, but would it be easier just to make a class?

Comment: No need for such a simple program.

Comment: Wow, didn't even occur to me that I was using array[size] instead of array[i]. Stupid of me, thank you

Comment: One more question, is there a problem with the way I use srand and rand? GDB says there is a problem with that function. @jfly

Comment: No problem, if you want to surpress the warning, add a cast: `srand((unsigned int)time(NULL))`

Comment: Did that, but I still get this error message.
0x00007ffff7756493 in srandom_r () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6

Comment: It's not the problem of `srand()`, your `fill_puzzle()` stuck in an infinite recursive call so that the stack segment is filled up, you get a segmentation fault.